# Changes/Deltas between two tables in Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql

I have a scenario where I want to find delta between two postgres tables. Suppose there are table A and Table B. I want to find the records which are newly added in Table A, then I need to find updated records in table A and then those records which are deleted in table A with respect to table B.

What will be the best way to do so as I need to later process those based on update/delete/insert flag.

Comment: Do those tables have a common unique column?

Comment: yes both tables are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a full outer join:

```
select id,
       case 
         when s.id is null then 'Deleted in source table'
         when t.id is null then 'Added in source table'
         else 'Data Changed'
       end as status
from source s 
  full outer join target t using (id)
where s is distinct from t;
```

This assumes that both tables a unique column named `id`.

The `where s is distinct from t` will compare all columns in both tables and thus will filter out all rows that exist in both and are identical. So the result is rows that are either missing in one of the tables or have different values.

Online example: http://rextester.com/LKY13449

Comment: I also want a flag to check which are the rows which are newly added and which are updated on or which are deleted from table A.

Comment: @AbhijeetSahai: that is the `status` column. I change the example to use your words

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is working. In my table all the fields are same and by running this query we are getting duplicate columns in our result set. any way to remove those and getting the same column structure like table A as both tables are same. I am not bothered about the table B data. I want to get only table A data.

Comment: @AbhijeetSahai: just select them explicitly from the table you want. Don't use `select *`